# URL in angular file upload is giving error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am uploading an image file via ng-file-upload(https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in angular fullstack.
Below is the code I am doing.
HTML:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-select ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB"/>
  Image thumbnail: <img ngf-src="file || '././assets/images/download.jpg'" style="width: 400px" class="thumbnail"><br>
<b>By clicking 'Submit' you agree to our Terms of Use & Posting Rules</b>
<button  ng-click="submit(file)" class="form-control;btn btn-success" style="width: 90px;display: inline">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submit = function(file) {
      if (file) {
        $scope.upload(file);
      }
    };
    // upload on file select or drop
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
      console.log("itnis getting hit");
        Upload.upload({
            url: '',
            data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log("executed");
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
          });
        };
```

Now I am not able to give the URL.It is giving 404 error when I write '/' in url.
I dont know if there is an error in my code or else.The directory structure of my project is here:
https://docs.google.com/a/innosols.co.in/document/d/1kyTtssJk8JwusYRSVW6bAaGe6Cj27H0FA0KA2bHQTQs/edit?usp=sharing

Since this is the first time I'm doing such a thing, I am totally frustrated it does not work. There are plenty of examples in the internet, providing the exactly same code - still this one does not work for me.

I would be happy about all suggestions, helping me to solve this problem.

Comment: anyone who can answer?

Comment: `./../assets/images/download.jpg` ?

Comment: I got the error.In url we have to give the url of our api so as to handle the file with multer and not the destination of the folder.This thing wasted my entire day.